# Adding to index of an element inside a typedef struct

Tags: c, indexing, enums, typedef

So I have a `typedef` struct which currently looks like this:

```
typedef struct Sys_Inject
{
   uint16_t num;
   uint16_t alternative;
   uint8_t  delay;
   uint8_t  thresh;
   uint8_t  reserved[2];
   BOOL32   state;
   options_select_t sel;
   uint32_t per;
} Sys_Inject_t;
```

I want to get rid of the elements `BOOL32 state;` and `options_select_t sel;` and define them inside the `uint8_t reserved[2]` array such that `reserved[0] = state` and `reserved[1] = sel`.
`BOOL32` is defined in another module and its data type is:

```
typedef BOOL32 (*FScallback_t)(uint32_t);
```

Also `options_select_t` is an enum and is defined as:

```
  typedef enum options_select_e
 {
    TEST_DEFAULT = 0,
    TEST_CURRENT,
    TEST_SAVED,
 }options_select_t;
```

If so how would I conduct this change?

Comment: Important note: There is no C/C++.  Two different languages that both branched off from a common source (1980s C) a long time ago and have been diverging ever since.

Comment: `typedef BOOL32 (*FScallback_t)(uint32_t);` defines `FScallback_t` (as pointer on function) not `BOOL32`.

Comment: If all you care about is a `0/1` (`true/false`) in `state` and `0`, `1`, `2` for `sel`, then you can remove both and replace with `uint8_t reserved[2];`, but it will be up to you to ensure you use both elements of the array correctly, ensuring that the value stored in them comply with this setup. You can easily run into problems if you attempt to store negative values or values greater than `255` in the elements. Now all existing code that uses `Sys_Inject_t` will break until you update it to remove reference to the removed members and add support for the new `reserved` member.

Comment: I would start from the C book. It is hard to program if you do not know what typedefs mean